# Custom XPath rule to check catch clauses in Java

Tags: java, xpath, sonarqube

I want to introduce a *new custom XPath rule* to SonarQube via its web interface that checks for the following case

```
try{
  doStuff();
} catch (SomeException e) {
  handleException(e);
}
```

which should be highlighted. Whereas

```
try{
  doStuff();
} catch (SomeException e) {
  LOG.info(e.getMessage() + " other stuff");
  handleException(e);
}
```

should be the desired form. Any idea how I can express it through XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you are writing about a PMD rule. Here is the XPath which match all the `catch` statements which does not have method `LOG.info` called anywhere inside:

```
//CatchStatement[not(descendant::PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image='LOG.info'])]
```

For example, for that code:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger; 

public class Test { 
private Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(""); 

    public void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            doStuff();
        } catch (SomeException e) { // HERE VIOLATION
            handleException(e);
        }
        try { 
            doStuff(); 
        } catch (SomeException e) { 
            LOG.info(e.getMessage() + " other stuff"); 
            handleException(e); 
        }
    }
}
```

it will find rule violation at line 9 (`} catch (SomeException e) { // HERE VIOLATION`) because in that line is catch statement which does not contain `LOG.info`.

I suggest you to use PMD designer app to write more complex PMDs. It generates Abstract Syntax Tree of your java code and gives possibility to write and check your XPath rules. You could find it [here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just tried the designer but the XPath expression returns "No matching nodes xxxx" for this code: import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
 private  Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("");
 public  void main(String[] args) {
try{
  doStuff();
} catch (SomeException e) {
  LOG.info(e.getMessage() + " other stuff");
  handleException(e);
}
 }
}

Comment: Isn't that correct? `No matching nodes` means that there are no code that match your XPath rule. In your catch statement is `LOG.info` call, so it doesn't violate rule. See edited answer for example.

Comment: I think I had some other unrelated issues that prevented the example from working. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record : @damgad you can also write your custom rules with Xpath expression using sonarqube rule engine. Not necessarily PMD.